# Tracking Installed App on enterprise iOS device

Tags: ios, swift3, mobile-application

I am developing an iOS Enterprise application. It is same as Apple app store containing couple of my company applications. I want to know which application the users has downloaded from the app so that i can keep a track of his downloaded installations and the current installed versions on his device. I am using Swift 3.0. How should I approach for acheiving this funcationality..
Any suggestion will really help!

Comment: That is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from your code out of the box. Device management is more complex in it's accessibility rights of the devices.

You need to use some kind of Mobile Device Management (MDM) software for that case. There are several services out there. Apple also has one on its own: https://support.apple.com/business
https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator

There are several other service providers available.
The link below might help you, find what you want:
As it is not really best practise posting links. If the link was broken, look for "List of Mobile Device Management Services" and you will find a bunch of alternatives to Apple's software.
http://www.pcmag.com/article/342695/the-best-mobile-device-management-mdm-software-of-2016

A short side note: I made experience with AirWatch and XenMobile so far. Get a Trial Account on their pages and check out, whether this fits your purpose and is worth the time spent to maintain the devices. Well, at last your purpose seems to me very limited to a certain request, which you could request from your user group in a different way?